# Relation between pointers and Arrays in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, declaration

I have these 3 cases from CLA certification ( C programming Language Certified associate Certification ; CPP Institute) that I would like to  understand better:

1. `int *array[10]`
2. `int (*array)[10]`
3. `int *(*array)[10]`

What are the differences between these 3 cases?

Comment: I suggest reading section 6 of the [comp.lang.c faq](http://c-faq.com/).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is an array name a pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641957/is-an-array-name-a-pointer)

Answer (score 2):

Here's what you have:

1. An array of 10 pointers to `int`.
2. A pointer to an array of 10 `int`.
3. A pointer to an array of 10 pointers to `int`.

Comment: Yeah sorry I read that wrong. So evidently "A pointer to an array of 10 `int*`" would be easier to read.

Comment: @Lundin Well, I expanded it fully into English.  Leaving `int *` would be an incomplete expansion.  This is the standard way to describe it without the use of any parentheses or brackets or asterisks, i.e. entirely in English.

Comment: Maybe it's just me being more fluent in the C language than the English language then :)

Comment: @Lundin Yeah, the English-language descriptions are cumbersome.  I only resort to them when people want an English-language description of a declaration.

Answer (score 0):

This

```
int *array[10]
```

is a declaration of an array with 10 elements of the type `int *`.

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    enum { N = 10 };
    int a[N] = 
    { 
        0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 
    };

    int * array[N] = 
    { 
        &a[0], &a[1], &a[2], &a[3], &a[4], &a[5], &a[6], &a[7], &a[8], &a[9] 
    };

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        printf( "%d ", a[i] );
    }
    putchar( '\n' );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        printf( "%d ", *array[i] );
    }
    putchar( '\n' );

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

This

```
int (*array)[10]
```

is a declaration of a pointer to an object having the array type `int[10]`.

Here is another demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    enum { N = 10 };
    int a[N] = 
    { 
        0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 
    };

    int (*array)[N] = &a;

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        printf( "%d ", a[i] );
    }
    putchar( '\n' );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        printf( "%d ", ( *array )[i] );
    }
    putchar( '\n' );

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is the same as above.

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

This

```
int *(*array)[10]
```

is a declaration of a pointer to an object of the array type `int *[10]`.

Here is one more demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    enum { N = 10 };
    int a[N] = 
    { 
        0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 
    };

    int * b[N] = 
    { 
        &a[0], &a[1], &a[2], &a[3], &a[4], &a[5], &a[6], &a[7], &a[8], &a[9] 
    };

    int *(*array)[N] = &b;

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        printf( "%d ", a[i] );
    }
    putchar( '\n' );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        printf( "%d ", *( *array )[i] );
    }
    putchar( '\n' );

    return 0;
}
```

Again its output the same as shown above.

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

In general if you have an array for example like this

```
T a[N1][N2][N3];
```

where `T` is some type specifier and `N1`, `N2`, `N3` are its sizes then a pointer to such an array will look like

```
T ( *p )[N1][N2][N3] = &a;
```

Dereferencing the pointer you will get lavlue of the array itself.

For example

`sizeof( *p )` is equal to the `sizeof( a[N1][N2][N3] )`.

Below is an example of more complicated declaration

```
int * ( * array[10] )[10];
```

It is a declaration of an array of 10 elements of pointers to arrays of 10 elements of pointer to the type `int`.

Here is a demonstrative program that shows how to process such an array. Investigate it.:)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    enum { N = 10 };
    int a[N] = 
    { 
        0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 
    };

    int * b[N] = 
    { 
        &a[0], &a[1], &a[2], &a[3], &a[4], &a[5], &a[6], &a[7], &a[8], &a[9] 
    };

    int * ( * array[N] )[N] = 
    { 
        &b, &b, &b, &b, &b, &b, &b, &b, &b, &b
    };

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        for ( size_t j = 0; j < N; j++ )
        {
            printf( "%d ",  ( **array[i] )[j] );
        }           
        putchar( '\n' );
    }
    putchar( '\n' );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```